# Python File Processing One Char At A Time

Tags: file, python-3.x, io

I need to read from a file until a certain character is hit without storing a whole line.

I tried this:

```
def read_one_fasta_entry(fStream) :
    s = '' # temp var
    while (s != '>') : # '>' is the char to read until and then discard/skip
        fStream.read(1)
```

However, this just sends the program into an infinite loop with the given input: 
*>fig|100226.1.peg.1 SCEND.02c, unknown, doubtful CDS, len: 225aa [Streptomyces coelicolor A3(2)]
MTGHHESTGPGTALSSDSTCRVTQYQTAGVNARLRLFALLERRACPRARRTTWWPGRSAR
WWSWTAWRRLLGVCCVRGRLGRRRDGGERGPGGHRGPGLATARRRSGGATELAVHCADVR
QRERADLVRLEGFVRESVLPRAHPHTTARRRVLEVLGEAGSLCTARTVNSDEDYILCTLG
VGHYDPDDQPPFKDGKPGWQRAGASIWNGSGAACIPHAAIEGPRK*

There are many more entries than the above and I need to store the ID (fig|10026.1.peg.1) and sequence (MTGHHE...) and was going to use the above method to process one char at a time as the file is deterministic ('>' before ID, ' ' to end ID, ']' before sequence) but it is not working. Any advice?

**EDIT
I have now updated the program and it seems to work for the most part, but it looks like I am getting offset by a '>'
My module:

```
def read_one_fasta_entry(fStream) :
    while (True) :
        s = ''
        while (s != '>') : # Discard first char/extra chars further in the file
            s = fStream.read(1)

        pegid = ''
        while (s != ' ') : # read one char at a time and append to pegid until whitespace
            s = fStream.read(1)
            pegid += s

        protseq = ''
        while (s != ']') : # read one char at a time and append to protseq until close square bracket
            s = fStream.read(1)

        while(s != '>') :
            s = fStream.read(1)
            protseq += s

        yield (pegid, protseq)
```

Driver:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

import p3mod


f = open(sys.argv[1])
for (pegid,protseq) in p3mod.read_one_fasta_entry(f):
    print(pegid,protseq)
f.close()
```

Any ideas on how to skip the first '>'? I am new to python but is there an equivalent of a 'do...while()' loop? It seems like it would be very effective here.

Comment: you are never setting your variable `s` to equal to your input so `s = ''` all the time.

Comment: This can't be your actual code; the parameter to the method is `fstream` (lowercase s), and later you use `fStream` (uppercase S). Please copy/paste your code _exactly_.

Comment: @RNar l0l wow that's embarrasing... Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @marcelm Apologies! I have updated it in the original post. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I figured it out! I had to offset the first skip of the '>' char (line 2) and check whether I reached the eof (line 19).
Here is my updated module (driver is in original post):

```
def read_one_fasta_entry(fStream) : # Return iterable two-tuples of (pegid, protseq) as long as eof is not reached
    s = fStream.read(1) # Offset skipping '>' char
    while (True) : # Loop to eof
        s = ''
        pegid = ''

        while (s != ' ') : # Read one char at a time and append to pegid until whitespace
            s = fStream.read(1)
            pegid += s

        protseq = ''
        while (s != ']') : # Read one char at a time and append to protseq until close square bracket
            s = fStream.read(1)

        while(s != '>' and s != '') : # Read until next entry (s != '>') or eof (s != '')
            s = fStream.read(1)
            if(s != '>') :
                protseq += s

        if(s == '') : # Check for eof
            yield (pegid, protseq)
            raise StopIteration() # Close generator

        yield (pegid, protseq)
```